# Why WinForm distroyed and demolished after working threadProc execution completes?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

I am facing a WinForm destroyal problem after the thread finishes as shown below, just a code will clear the picture.

```
//Constructor
=============

private HookCoreMangerClass()//ref ApplicationInfo mCurrentAttachedApplicationInfo)
{
    m_ContainerHandler = new ControlsContainerMgt();            
    m_hThreadAsyncControls = new Thread(this.GetControlsAsynchronously);
    m_hThreadAsyncControls.Start();
    ...
    ...
}
public void GetControlsAsynchronously()
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.Suspend();
    List<CustomControl> Objects = null;
    IntPtr ContainerHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
    if (m_IHooker != null)
    {
        m_IHooker.GetControlsHandles(m_processHandle, out Objects);
        List<ITAKOControl> ListOfControls = new List<ITAKOControl>();
        foreach (CustomControl customControl in Objects)
        {
            ITAKOControl TakoControlHandler = factry.CreateControl(customControl);                    
            TakoControlHandler.setPropeties(customControl);
            ContainerHandle = m_ContainerHandler.GetHandle();
            TakoControlHandler.SetContainer(ContainerHandle);
            ListOfControls.Add(TakoControlHandler);                    
        }
        m_ParentForm = Control.FromHandle(ContainerHandle);

        m_ParentForm.Show();
        m_ParentForm.Refresh();
        m_ParentForm.Update();
    }
}
```

I consumed and house-kept the handle of thread `"GetControlsAsynchronously"` at the top of the constructor. As the control passes through the end of this function (thread proc GetControlsAsynch) it just gets demolished and the main process GUI is still there. What can be the reason for this?

## Note :

"ControlsContainerMgt " is a separate class library whose instance this process keep where 
ControlsContainerMgt is :

```
public class ControlsContainerMgt : Form
{                
    public ControlsContainerMgt()
    {
        base.Text = "Tsdfsfd";
        base.Name = "sads";
    }
    public IntPtr GetHandle()
    {
        return base.Handle;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Could it be related to cross-thread operations? Have you tried to check for InvokeRequired in the control, and Invoke as appropriate?

Comment: Elbaorat it? Cross-thread operations? I just developed a samll dll containing 2 functions namely GetHandle() which returns the handle(IntPtr) and Constructor of its class and MAINLY this class just inherting "/Form" inheritance. So , I am just calling its show method from the bottom of Thread Proc procedure. That's all!!. See above. The form is yet displayed on screen, but as control passes outside the thread, it just gone away and demolished, even I have handle of its Form at class level. What could be the reason?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Jonas : My problem is clearly written, my form which actually created by its parent process not showing after the thread which just called its show method completed its execution in debugging mode. As that threads completed, Form whose class created at constructor level even, gone and disappear, while the parent process is still running

Comment: That seems more like an implementation problem and not the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Be aware that Windows Forms isn't thread safe. You should only manipulate controls and such from the UI-thread.

Comment: So why above behavior my application is following? The thread which shown the form, when that dies( dies just means the functionality it was assigned, it just completed ) , Form also dies, which have several controls at different places. :-(

Comment: Do I need to create extra seperate process instead of just a class extending Form as a seperate DLL hosted inside parent process, and thus constructing all controls on the Fly in that process with the usage of Reflection at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should clone the control in your side otherwise the reference will represent the real one.
In manage code handle passed as reference.
Try to clone the control to have real instance (duplicate the control), otherwise you will have few references to one instance.